# Как сделать кнопку назад?

Tags: python, tkinter

Как в этом коде сделать кнопку назад и где мне сделать def back(), чтобы оно видело все виджеты, которые находятся в коде и чтобы все виджеты видели эту функцию и могли её выполнить

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from pythonping import ping
import string
import secrets

win = Tk()
win.geometry("375x250")
win.resizable(0,0)
win.title("All-in-one")

# defs
Input1 = StringVar()
def default():
    def sitep():
        def showping(event=None):
            try:
                win.geometry("450x210")
                myLabel4 = Label(win, text="Ожидайте...", font=("Montserrat", 11))
                myLabel4.pack()
                win.update()
                myLabel4.destroy()
                win.geometry("450x190")
                tk.messagebox.showinfo("Пинг", "- Результаты пинга:\n" + str(ping(Input1.get(), verbose=True, count=5)) + "\n\nПримечание: возможно, создатель сайта закрыл доступ для отправки пакетов на его сайт, поэтому некоторые рабочие сайты могут не пинговаться")
            except:
                myLabel4.destroy()
                tk.messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", "- Произошла ошибка, проверьте правильность написания IP-адреса или ссылки")
        win.geometry("450x190")
        myLabel1.destroy()
        myButton1.destroy()
        myButton2.destroy()
        myButton3.destroy()
        myLabel2 = Label(win, text="Пинг", font=("Montserrat", 20), highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=2, width=5)
        myLabel2.pack()
        myLabel3 = Label(win, text="Введите ссылку или IP-адрес", font=("Montserrat", 18))
        myLabel3.pack()
        myInput1 = Entry(win, font=("Montserrat", 15), textvariable=Input1, justify=LEFT, width=30, highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=2)
        myInput1.pack(ipady=2)
        myInput1.bind('<Return>', showping)
        myButton4 = Button(win, text="Принять", font=("Montserrat", 15), command=showping)
        myButton4.pack(ipady=2, pady=5)
        myButton6 = Button(win, text="Назад", font=("Montserrat", 15), command=back)
    myLabel1 = Label(win, text="Способы", font=("Montserrat", 20))
    myLabel1.pack()
    myButton1 = Button(win, text="Пинг", font=("Montserrat", 16), width=17, command=sitep)
    myButton1.pack(pady=6)
    myButton2 = Button(win, text="Длина текста", font=("Montserrat", 16), width=17)
    myButton2.pack(pady=6)
    myButton3 = Button(win, text="Генератор паролей", font=("Montserrat", 16), width=17)
    myButton3.pack(pady=6)

# widgets
default()

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать отдельные окна для отдельных действий. Тогда не придётся персобирать элементы окна каждый раз.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from pythonping import ping
import string
import secrets


def back(current, parent):
    current.destroy()   # уничтожаем текущее окно
    parent.deiconify()  # показываем родительское окно

def win_ping(parent):
    def showping(event=None):
        try:
            win.geometry("450x210")
            myLabel4 = Label(win, text="Ожидайте...", font=("Montserrat", 11))
            myLabel4.pack()
            win.update()
            myLabel4.destroy()
            win.geometry("450x190")
            tk.messagebox.showinfo("Пинг", "- Результаты пинга:\n" + str(ping(Input1.get(), verbose=True, count=5)) + "\n\nПримечание: возможно, создатель сайта закрыл доступ для отправки пакетов на его сайт, поэтому некоторые рабочие сайты могут не пинговаться")
        except:
            myLabel4.destroy()
            tk.messagebox.showerror("Ошибка", "- Произошла ошибка, проверьте правильность написания IP-адреса или ссылки")

    Input1 = StringVar()

    parent.withdraw()   # прячем родительское окно
    win = tk.Toplevel() # создаём новое окно
    win.geometry("450x190")
    win.resizable(0,0)
    myLabel2 = Label(win, text="Пинг", font=("Montserrat", 20), highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=2, width=5)
    myLabel2.pack()
    myLabel3 = Label(win, text="Введите ссылку или IP-адрес", font=("Montserrat", 18))
    myLabel3.pack()
    myInput1 = Entry(win, font=("Montserrat", 15), textvariable=Input1, justify=LEFT, width=30, highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=2)
    myInput1.pack(ipady=2)
    myInput1.bind('<Return>', showping)

    myFrame = Frame(win)
    myFrame.pack(ipady=2, pady=5)
    myButton4 = Button(myFrame, text="Принять", font=("Montserrat", 15), command=showping)
    myButton4.pack(side=LEFT, padx=15)
    myButton6 = Button(myFrame, text="Назад", font=("Montserrat", 15), command=lambda: back(win, parent))
    myButton6.pack(side=LEFT, padx=15)
    win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: back(win, parent))  # обработчик закрытия окна по стандартной кнопке в правом верхнем углу

def main():
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry("375x250")
    win.resizable(0,0)
    win.title("All-in-one")
    myLabel1 = Label(win, text="Способы", font=("Montserrat", 20))
    myLabel1.pack()
    myButton1 = Button(win, text="Пинг", font=("Montserrat", 16), width=17, command=lambda: win_ping(win))
    myButton1.pack(pady=6)
    myButton2 = Button(win, text="Длина текста", font=("Montserrat", 16), width=17)
    myButton2.pack(pady=6)
    myButton3 = Button(win, text="Генератор паролей", font=("Montserrat", 16), width=17)
    myButton3.pack(pady=6)
    win.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](https://coderoad.ru/11100380/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-Python3-Tkinter-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4) есть всë, что Вам нужно: